# HQL Query to fetch details from two tables

Tags: mysql, hql

HQL Query to fetch details from two tables.

I'm trying to get details from two table using hibernate query.

I have two tables:

1) `Employee_Details` with table details:

```
EMP_ID, EMPNAME DETAILS, ETC
2,      Damat,           jjj, ljllj, jhkgk,
```

2) `EMPLOYEE_MANAGER` with table details:

```
EMPLOYEE_MANAGER_ID, PROJECT_INFO, EMP_ID
241,                 testmanger,   2
```

From `employee_details` table I have to get the `EMPLOYEE_MANAGER_ID 241`

How I can query using hibernate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT EMPLOYEE_MANAGER.EMPLOYEE_MANAGER_ID
FROM Employee_Details
INNER JOIN EMPLOYEE_MANAGER ON Employee_Details.EMP_ID = Employee_Details.EMP_ID
WHERE Details.EMP_ID=2
```

You can try this in MySQL.

Comment: what is your input..?

Comment: input the emp_id and empname and get the  employee_manager_id as integer

Comment: getting Column 'EMP_ID' in where clause is ambiguous

Comment: you have to use `Details.EMP_ID`  instead of  `EMP_ID`.